# My code in rust returns: thread 'main' panicked at 'removal index (is 2) should be < len (is 2)'

Tags: rust

I'm trying make a program that uses rand to show the success rate guessing a door (like in a TV show). It compiles but don't run.

```
use rand::Rng;


fn main() {
    let mut right_answers = 0.0;
    for _ in 0..100 {
        let mut not_already_chosen: Vec<usize> = vec![1, 2, 3];
        let mut rng = rand::thread_rng();

        let right_door = rng.gen_range(1..4);

        let mut guest_choice: usize = rng.gen_range(1..4);
        not_already_chosen.remove(guest_choice);

        let presenter_choice = not_already_chosen[rng.gen_range(0..not_already_chosen.len())];
        not_already_chosen.remove(presenter_choice);

        guest_choice = not_already_chosen[0];

        if guest_choice == right_door {
            right_answers += 1.0;
        }
    }
    println!("Rate: {}", (right_answers / 100.0));
}
```

When I use cargo run it returns:

```
Compiling choose_the_door v0.1.0 (.../choose_the_door)
    Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 0.47s
     Running `target/debug/choose_the_door`
thread 'main' panicked at 'removal index (is 2) should be < len (is 2)', src/main.rs:16:28
note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
```

I tried to remove some parts of the code to see what is wrong. When I remove the lines that has 'not_already_chosen.remove(...);' it runs but the code don't do what I wanted at first. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What I'm doing wrong?

You're using `Vec::remove` wrong. It looks like you expect it to remove the item you provide, but it removes the item at the index you provide:

> Removes and returns the element at position index within the vector, shifting all elements after it to the left.

So depending on luck of the draw:

1. it can panic at the guest choice line 13 because the guest chooses 1, 2, or 3, so 1/3rd of the time it'll select 3 which is out of range for the vector, and panic
2. if (1) passes, you've left with a vector of length 2 which is either [1, 3] or [2, 3], line 15 will access a random index in 0..3, so 0, 1, or 2. 1/3rd of the time the index will be 2, and line 15 will panic
3. finally if both (1) and (2) passed, you try to remove the index you got from (2), which is either 1, 2, or 3. Since the vector still has length 2 because of (1), only "1" would pass

This means the chances of passing through the entire thing is 1/9th: (1) must select 2, then (2) must select 0, which results in (3) getting the index 1 and actually passing.

Except you're looping 100 times, meaning the odds of going through the entire thing successfully and reaching line 25 (loop exit) is (1/9)<sup>100</sup>, which is basically 0 (it's 3.7e<sup>-96</sup>, if every atom in the universe ran this program once, the odds of one of them getting it would still be about 1e<sup>-14</sup>, for reference powerball jackpot odds are 3.4e<sup>-9</sup>)